# Encoding Request parameters for preventing Cross Site Scripting Attacks giving Encoded values in Omniture Report

Tags: javascript, security, encoding, adobe-analytics

I have encoding many request parameters in Javascript function to prevent Cross Site Scripting Attacks. After Encoding, all the special characters are appearing as corresponding encoded value in report. I want to encode the value to prevent attacks but want to capture the  corresponding decoded values. 
`EncodeURIComponent(Hello+);` Now it is neccesary to encode values to prevent attacks but I want to register the value as Hello+, not Hello%20 something.

Answer (score 0):

To get `+` instead of `%20`, call `replace` on the output of `encodeURIComponent`:

```javascript
str = encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%20/g, '+');
```

However, I can't imagine the circumstance in which `encodeURIComponent` is the correct function to use to prevent XSS. Technically it will work (except inside single-quoted attribute values), but it will mangle the output. XSS only occurs in HTML, so I think you might want an HTML escaping function instead:

```javascript
function escapeHtml(text) {
    return text.replace(/[&"'<>]/g, function(c) {
        return (
            c == '&' ? '&amp;' :
            c == '"' ? '&quot;' :
            c == "'" ? '&#039;' :
            c == '<' ? '&lt;' : '&gt;'
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have many javascript functions on my jsp Pages. I am taking request parameters and assigning them to some variables. so if I replace the encoded value with the corresponding special character value, the problem still persist. you can test it by putting alert with some request parameter in the URL. On hitting Enter , the alert will popup. So with encoding corresponding () will be change to encoded values and alert will not appear. If I replace the encoded value with the (), the problem still persists.

Comment: Was this a reply to my answer? I've no idea what you're trying to say. If you still need help, please show the code.